# ARKit Object not created from saved file

Tags: swift, arkit

I am working for a project using ARKit. I need to save an object position For example in my Home I set a chair/object centre in my room and come back to room after few hours later I wish to see that chair/object on that place where it was is it possible in ARKit.

I placed my chair/object and saved in file the file saved successfully. But when i retrieve the saved file and reload objects. But the Object not visible in ARSession

```
    let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
    configuration.planeDetection = [.horizontal]

    let options: ARSession.RunOptions = [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors]
    if let worldMap = worldMap {
        configuration.initialWorldMap = worldMap
        print("Found saved world map.")
        self.showAlert("Found saved world map.", "")
    } else {
        print("Move camera around to map your surrounding space.")
    }
    sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: options)
    sceneView.delegate = self
```

Answer (score -1):

When you place the chair, you need to add an anchor to your scene:

```
  let anchor = ARAnchor(name: "chair", transform: transform)
  session.add(anchor: anchor)
```

Then you implement the `ARSCNViewDelegate` and add your actual model to the anchor.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    guard anchor.name == "chair" else { return }
    node.addChildNode(chairNode)
}
```

So what is happening? When you save an `ARWorldMap` it contains all anchors, but no SceneKit data. 
That's why we need to first add the anchor that lates is saved and add the geometry in the delegate. The delegate is called both when you manually add an anchor and when the system adds anchors after you run the session with a new initial world map.

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/creating_a_persistent_ar_experience):

> The same ARSCNView delegate method renderer(_:didAdd:for:) fires both when you directly add an anchor to the session and when the session restores anchors from a world map. To determine which saved anchor represents the virtual object, this app uses the ARAnchor name property.

Comment: its not called delegate every-time when user retrieve  file and reload object. I already test this and i am stuck why its not reload every time.

Comment: It is called. Does the relocalization actually work? You can check the `.trackingState` of the `ARCamera` and look for the [`.relocalization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/trackingstate/reason/relocalizing) reason.

Comment: its work sometimes ... actually user can reload object every time .. that issue.. sometimes its show .. when user refresh sceneview and reload again its not visible

Comment: The objects will only get added after the scene is relocalized